# ORMLite dropping data when adding a column to the table

Tags: android, sql, ormlite

In my Android app, I'm using ORMLite to store data into local database, and when adding a column to that database using `onUpgrade()` method, I'm getting all the data of that table to be erased.
I'm using [upgrade schema](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Upgrading-Schema) way mentioned in ORMLite documentation:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVer, int newVer) {

    try {
        if(oldVer < 10){
            getGuardiansDao().executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `messages` ADD COLUMN updated_by TEXT;");
            getGuardiansDao().executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `messages` ADD COLUMN updated_by_time TEXT;");
        }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
           Log.e(DBManager.class.getName(), "Unable to upgrade database from version " + oldVer + " to new "
                + newVer, e);
        }
}
```

And in the class assigned to that table:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "messages")
public class Message extends Object implements Parcelable{

.
.
.
    @DatabaseField
    private String updatedBy;

    @DatabaseField
    private String updatedByTime;

}
```

Now after executing that it erases all the data stored in the table `messages` and I don't have any clue why that is happening.

Comment: @Gray yeah you are right, in fact it is an extremely silly mistake, after deep checking I found that the problem is that it can't map the new column name with the name in the assigned class duo to a slight change I didn't take care of, I don't know why that was not appearing before but that was the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now after executing that it erases all the data stored in the table messages and I don't have any clue why that is happening.

Certainly the code that you've posted won't erase the table and ORMLite doesn't do that automatically or anything.  Is there any chance the `onCreate(...)` method is being called instead for some reason?

There are many ways to debug this but you could log the contents of the table using raw statements in the `onUpgrade(...)` method to ensure that the table is being correctly built.  Then you might be able to detect when it has been cleared.